# Embed a Flow in a lightning web Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-flows

Is there a way in LWC, to call flow from web components. I have a task where I need to add flow into Global action traditionally its not possible with salesforce out-of-box functionality. I'm able to do it via aura component. I wanted to know if there is a way to implement it in LWC.

Answer (score 9):

You can embed a flow in LWC using the new `lightning-flow` component (from Winter '23 platform release).

To embed a flow simply use the below:

```
 <lightning-flow flow-api-name="flow_api_name"
                            flow-input-variables={inputVariables}
                            onstatuschange={handleStatusChange}
                        >
 </lightning-flow>
```

Here ***flow_api_name*** is assumed to be the API name of the flow. Note this can be dynamic and you can pass this via JavaScript controller.

**flow-input-variables** is where you can pass in input variables from lwc to the Flow. You will need a function like below in the JavaScript controller

```
get inputVariables() {
    return [
        {
            name: "recordId",
            type: "String",
            value: this.recordId
        }
    ];
}
```

**onstatuschange** is how you can handle the status changes in flow including flow finish behavior.

```
handleStatusChange(event) {
    if (event.detail.status === "FINISHED") {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Question was the other way around.....

Comment: For global action override one could just use flows and flows can have lwc in them. The other workaround is use aura as it allows both

Comment: For a possible workaround, check out this: https://unofficialsf.com/how-to-launch-flows-from-your-own-lightning-web-component/

Comment: This now wants to be updated to cover the Winter '23 `lightning-flow` feature.

Comment: Yes I have in my backlog to update few of answers! Embedding flows in LWC is an exciting update! We are thrilled about how one could do dependency injection with it.