# Invoke ScreenFlow on click of button in LWC component

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I have three flows , a main flow and two sub-flows .I need to invoke the Main flow from button in LWC component I was thinking around if we can embed main flow in LWC Component invoked from a button in another LWC component, but seems that is currently not possible in LWC any possible workaround for this ?
also I would like to return to the parent LWC component once the flow and subflows finish and refresh the parent LWC component but this refresh i think I can handle later

I saw one link for similar question on LWC but the code added here seems is not supported at present and will be part of Winter 23 release

[Embed a Flow in a lightning web Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310081/embed-a-flow-in-a-lightning-web-component/386637#386637)

Comment: If you can't wait a week or two, consider the [unofficialsf.com](https://unofficialsf.com/how-to-launch-flows-from-your-own-lightning-web-component/) options. However, I would recommend you simply wait for Winter '23 to be available - it's literally [just round the corner](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2022/admin-winter-23-release-dates-countdown).

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce provided the lwc attribute to launch flow from LWC
[Launch Screen Flows With Lightning Web Components](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_lwc_launch_screen_flows.htm&release=240&type=5)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.